# SQL inner query trying to use alias in the where clause

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a join of 2 tables, that represent a list of payments that contracts have done.

[Sample Query: (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iXGxgDTopsBBgXGUJsXpa/13)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iXGxgDTopsBBgXGUJsXpa/13)

That sample data consist of 5 contracts, some of them are running behind in payments, so I want to get the list of contracts that havent done a payment in the last 7 days, considering the current date to be: 9 of may of 2021.

For the example, contracts 121, 300, 321 and 400 have made a payment in the last 7 days, so any records from them should not appear in the final query. However:

- Contract 321 despite of a payment in the last 7 days they had a reversal that was the total of the credits made by them in the last 7 days, this is equivalent to 0 payments, so I want this contract to appear in my final query.
- Contract 121, I dont want to appear in the final result becuase despite of the reversal the is a total credits of 20 (100 credit - 80 reversal)
- Contract 400 I want to appear in my results because one of the rows has as codename Special Delete.

In the fiddle I was able to create the query that Filters all records with payments in the last 7 days, but I need help adding the extra filtering:

- If any contract that appear there if the sum of the credits and debits is 0, then appear it should appear in the final result (as it is like no payments have been send) this will be the case for the contract 321.
- If the credits are positive but one of the rows has as codename "SpecialDelete" then display it in the final result (this is the case for the contract 400)
- Total Debits against total credits greater than 0

I will be using this query with AWS Athena

I am guessing the part I need to ammend is (WHERE  Payments.ContractID NOT IN ....):

```
SELECT PaymentID,
  Payments.ContractID,
  PaymentDate,
  Credit,
  Debit,
  Code,
  CodeName,
  amount,
  city
FROM Payments 
LEFT JOIN Info ON Info.ContractID = Payments.ContractID
WHERE  Payments.ContractID NOT IN (
  SELECT Payments.ContractID
  FROM Payments 
  WHERE PaymentDate >= '20210501'
)
ORDER BY PaymentDate DESC
;
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer if the sample data were in the question.  It is rather silly to refer to a fiddle to understand such details about a question.

Comment: @godon, I respect your opinion but strongly disagree, having a fiddle hello me keeping the question cleaner and help me check the below answer, having sample data will make the post long and potentially lose the interest of them people who knows and might have helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you guess is correct, Here is what you need (if I didn't miss anything):

```
SELECT p.ContractID,PaymentDate,Credit,Debit,Code,CodeName,amount,city
FROM Payments  p
LEFT JOIN Info ON Info.ContractID = p.ContractID
WHERE  p.ContractID NOT IN (
  SELECT p2.ContractID
  FROM Payments p2
  WHERE p2.PaymentDate >= '20210501'
  group by p2.ContractID
  having sum(p2.credit - p2.debit) > 0 
) or codename = 'Special Delete'
ORDER BY PaymentDate DESC;
```